# Text is not being recognized correctly in an if statement

Tags: python-tesseract

I have an image that shows the text "Cafnote". Pytesseract recognizes this, and correctly sets the variable text = "Cafnote". I then check to see if text == 'Cafnote', and if it is, I want to print "Cafnote Found!", but right now the if statement returns false. How would I get this if statement to return true?

```
import PIL
from cv2 import cv2
import pytesseract
import time

while 1 < 6:
    time.sleep(1)
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot('screenshot.png', region=(1441,198,219,48))
    img = cv2.imread(r'screenshot.png')
    median = cv2.medianBlur(img,7)

    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(median)
    print(text)

    if text == 'Cafnote':
        print("Cafnote Found!")
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan. Perhaps an example image might be useful for quick help. And have you checked the capitalisation and escape characters like newline character?

Comment: The exact output is "Cafnote", with a weird up arrow on the next line that it doesn't let me copy and paste. Idk if the up arrow is normal, but it appears everytime I use pytesseract.

Comment: You were right, their was some sort of white space, and the arrow was not normal. Thank You!

Comment: It now doesn't have any weird characters, but it recognizes "Kabunga" as "Kabunoaa". Is their any way to restrict what it identifies it as? cause it will be 1 of 4 names

Comment: The problem with screenshots is that they don't have clarity. So try to do a little more pre-processing - binarizing, morphological transformations to increase the clarity. Tesseract works best with binarized images. And if the text does not have some empty region around it, then add some padding using cv2.copyMakeBorder()